# Can the header tag contain more than 1 nav tag?

Tags: html, header, nav

for example, I have a network nav menu at the top of the page which contains links to sites across the network and my main nav contains navigation to this site. Can both of these nav items be in the same header tag in html5? So I would have something like

```
<header>
   <nav id="nav_network"></nav>
   logo and stuff
   <nav id="nav_site"></nav>
</header>
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 2):

This is fine by the validator:

http://validator.w3.org/check

(As long as you include a `head` and a `title` in the doc)

Usually, though, you would place the `nav` outside the `header`.

`Header` is more like the title, logo, and a search form.

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading
>   (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but this is not required. The
>   header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents,
>   a search form, or any relevant logos.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element

More here: http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

Comment: hmmm.. I will take the network nav out of the header and keep the site nav inside of the header. thank you

Comment: You say that a `nav` isn't usually placed inside a `header` and yet the w3 article you cited has a code example featuring a `nav` nested inside a `header`. What?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in using **Multiple** nav in header, it is **perfectly** fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert more than one  element; that is the answer if you are basically asking about the availability. You can use more than one  element, and the browser will read your code perfectly since the  element is read as a  element in your browser, and there is no difference between them.

But as an SEO wise it is not recommended because the  is telling search engines where they can find your navigation menu. So, it is supposed to use only one navigation bar on your website.

Briefly, you can do that, but it is not recommended.