# Can i use more than one nav element for main body

Tags: html

Hey guys i am quite new to html5 and i was reading spec but i am a bit confused.
Can I use more than one `nav` element on main page?
I have a navigation on front of a big `bg` image and below as user scrolls the little nav  is fixed at top.
please give me some advice.
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the header tag contain more than 1 nav tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321050/can-the-header-tag-contain-more-than-1-nav-tag)

Comment: @Juhana i am asking about multiple navs inside body for main page

Comment: You're probably being voted down because you haven't shown the research you've already done. Quote the text you've read. Why is that confusing? Have you tried using the [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)? Why is the response from that unsatisfactory to you? Provide a sample of the HTML you are asking about. Anything to help target the question to help us provide an accurate and specific answer to you.

Comment: @Alohci so it means i can use the validator to check if it ok or not? will it give me all answers.?

Comment: Normally yes. At least for beginners. Technically, there are a few situations which are not machine checkable. Such as whether the text in an alt attribute makes sense or not. But for situations like your question, it will give you an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use multiple nav element in body.

Comment: Add sources to W3C to be more constructive.